# Is it possible for a client on a secure websocket connection to view the data being sent?

Tags: networking, encryption, websocket

I'm looking to create a simple wrapper to use some features of a website through python - in order to do so I need to figure out what requests are being sent to the server over secure websockets.

Chromes dev tools will show that there is data being sent, but will not allow me to view the data:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZYde.png]

Wireshark informs me that the application data is encrypted - is there any way for me to sniff my own traffic and decrypt the data so I can view what requests are being sent/received?

This is on a secure websocket or wss:// connection.

Comment: When it is a website, it uses javascript. Why don't you just look at the script to find out what it sends? You can use the javascript debugger to place a break-point on the `socket.send(message)` call.

Comment: [OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) is an excellent tool for this.

Comment: Unfortunately the javascript is heavily obfuscated (http://pastebin.com/HmgYD1Dn) - that's just a small snippet out of the 50,000 LOC.  @GregS - OWASP Zed attack proxy looked promising, but the website seemed to error when I used it as a proxy for my browser.

Comment: Try it on another website, for example https://www.google.com to debug the configuration. It is a little tricky to get right at first.

Comment: did you perhaps ever find a solution?

Comment: @AryehArmon Unfortunately not and as this post was for a hobby project of minor importance I left it in the 'to-do someday' bin, where it remains today :)